# Possibilities of these two apps running on same Process Resources

Tags: android, process, package-name

What if I install an App having Package Name: com.test.

And then install another app having package name: com.test.deeper

Are there any possibilities of these two apps running on same Process Resources?

Comment: No. Each app creates its own main process (plus more if you so define). If you need to use resources from a different app that app has to implement a public ContentProvider providing access to said resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two apps can run on same process but in your case it won't be the case.

Check the link

You just need to assign same values to android:shareUserID and android:process in both applications and sign them with same certificate.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html - shareUserId property 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html - process property
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html - general description

[you can also check for shared resources between apps](http://justanapplication.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/two-android-applications-a-shared-ui-element-and-a-shared-process-a-tale-of-classloaders-and-confusion/)